# How do I use a custom font in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I understand how to add a .tff file into my project but I haven't been able to find a post that makes it clear how and where to implement the font once it's been added. I found a post that says to implement the font like this:

var typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (context.Assets, fileName);

But I don't know where I should add this line of code, or what I should use in place of context. Can someone give me a basic explanation so I know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using a template created `Xamarin.Android` single Activity application:

Add a font to the Assets directory with a build type of `AndroidAsset`:

```
├── Assets
│   ├── AboutAssets.txt
│   └── Jellee-Roman.ttf
```

In the `OnCreate` add the following:

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);

// Add these two lines:
var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "Jellee-Roman.ttf");  
button.Typeface = font;

button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
```

Comment: It is a good practice to put the font files in a _fonts_ folder, in the Assets folder still. And pick it up like that `fonts/Jellee-Roman.ttf`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the reference to the `Typeface`, you can then set it into the `TextView` via the following:

`Typeface` property - https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Widget.TextView.Typeface/

`SetTypeface` method - https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Widget.TextView.SetTypeface/p/Android.Graphics.Typeface/Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the font of a textview, then in your `OnCreate` method put this after you do FindViewById:

```
var typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "filename.ttf");
myTextView.TypeFace = typeface;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be generic, and use as style, you can do this in the .axml (the font need to be into "Resources/Font/PermanentMarker.ttf"):

```
 <TextView
        ...
        android:fontFamily="@font/permanentmarker"/>
```